# Best Java/Swing browser component?

Tags: java, swing, browser

What's the best cross platform Java Swing browser component at least able to play nicely in a swing interface (lightweight component ?) and able to run on MacOSX and Windows ?

Things like : [FlyingSaucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//), [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/), maybe others ?

Comment: You can find how to embed an HTML rendering component into Swing here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754819/363573

Comment: A similar question with more up-to-date answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707231/web-browser-control-in-java

Answer (score 36, accepted):

i belive this could help:

http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html

Comment: I tried them all, DJ is the best

Comment: Well their webstart doesn't demo doesn't launch! Boo.

Comment: It runs on Mac OS as well, even on new Lion.

Comment: I could not find a method to integrate it into netbeans, so it seems useless.

Comment: @backTangent Did you try the following solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754819/363573

Comment: @backTangent If you've got a NetBeans Maven project you can easily integrate it by adding the following depedencies : 
- DJNativeSwing, 
- DJNativeSwing-SWT, 
- org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86

Answer (score 5):

The Lobo Browser could be what you're looking for:

http://lobobrowser.org/index.jsp

It's GPL and renders JavaFX as well as HTML

---

#### Edit

JavaFX 2.0 comes with a Browser component:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Comment: Lobo is almost useless, in that too many websites don't render right.

Comment: @Mike Here is an alternative to Lobo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27754819/363573

Comment: @Stephan or use Java 8's web view component

Comment: @Stephan I'm nervous about introducing a whole other native SWT rendering subsystem. Eclipse still after all these years still shows redrawing bugs for instance (which uses SWT).

Comment: @tim_yates I've contemplated this in the past. At one point there was a promise that web-view would be a way to use the WebKit based browser component, but that it wasn't available on Linux. However, from what I gathered, these days, both with Java 7 and 8, one can expect web-view to simply work on Linux (and Windows and Mac). Is that correct?
Of course, I'd have to shoe-horn the JavaFX based web-view component into my Swing application using the right wrappers. Why couldn't Oracle simply have made available a JWebView or something like that?

Comment: Link not working

Comment: Things move on over 10 years

Comment: Javafx now has a pretty decent browser component