# cross domain DOM access and manipulation in Java?

Tags: java, cross-domain, javascript

In my Java app, how can I incorporate the browser (which loads and renders URLs) in Swing  and access it's DOM and manipulate HTML ?

How can you embed such browser in a Rich Internet Application and access it's DOM ? More specifically, Vaadin ? Is there a HTTP proxy class that can load an external URL, and render it to the user ? This was what I was doing on LAMP stack....but I want to switch to Vaadin or some Java web framework where I can just use Java to do everything from server-side to client-side logic design, so I can focus more on application logic. (aka looking for developer friendly frameworks like Vaadin).

Thank you and have a great weekend !

Comment: See [How to display html in a java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817609/how-to-display-html-in-a-java-application), in particular [DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/).

Comment: yes i am looking for something like that but it must work with a web framework like Vaadin

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans have been making strides in this direction. See their [wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/EmbeddedBrowserPlan68), but I don't think they can get hold of the DOM.