# Embed Firefox browser in Java Swing

Tags: java, firefox, swing

I am wondering if it is possible to embed Firefox browser as a component in a Java Swing based application.

I have done a bit of research from the Internet, but I could not find an answer. Some people suggest to use other browser component available in Java. I do not think that is preferable, as the rendering engine would be different to Firefox.

Any idea? Many thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Absolutely I have done it before please check out the [Mozilla Embedding for Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaXPCOM)

Here is some sample code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.File; 

import javax.swing.*;

import org.mozilla.xpcom.*; 
import org.mozilla.interfaces.*;

/*
Websites ref
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.java/browse_thread/thread/898ba6751d0c57f7 
http://skrul.com/blog/code/
http://wirestorm.net/blog/?cat=9

*/


public class BrowserTest  implements nsIWebProgressListener,nsIWeakReference, nsIInterfaceRequestor, nsIWebBrowserChrome, nsISHistoryListener{ 
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("NativeWindow");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("can't find your library");
        }
    }
    private static final String frameTitle="GRE Embedded";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserConroller controler=new BrowserConroller();
        controler.run();
        new BrowserTest().start();
    } 

    public void start(){


        JFrame f = new JFrame( frameTitle );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 150);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        content.add(new JLabel("Initializing ... "));
        f.setVisible(true);

        File grePath = null; 
        LocationProvider locProvider; 
        Mozilla mozilla = Mozilla.getInstance(); 

        GREVersionRange[] range = new GREVersionRange[1]; 
        range[0] = new GREVersionRange("1.8.0", true, "1.9", false); 

        try { 
            grePath = Mozilla.getGREPathWithProperties(range, null);
            mozilla.initialize(grePath);
            locProvider = new LocationProvider(grePath); 
            mozilla.initEmbedding(grePath, grePath, locProvider); 
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("Error: FileNotFoundException"); 
        } 
        catch (XPCOMException e) { 
            System.out.println("Error: XPCOMException"); 
        } 


        //---------- END GRE INITIALIZATION------------


        nsIServiceManager serviceManager = mozilla.getServiceManager(); 

        nsIAppStartup appStartup = (nsIAppStartup)serviceManager.getServiceByContractID("@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1", nsIAppStartup.NS_IAPPSTARTUP_IID); 
        nsIWindowCreator windowCreator = (nsIWindowCreator)appStartup.queryInterface(nsIWindowCreator.NS_IWINDOWCREATOR_IID); 

        nsIWindowWatcher windowWatcher =(nsIWindowWatcher)serviceManager.getServiceByContractID("@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1",nsIWindowWatcher.NS_IWINDOWWATCHER_IID); 

        windowWatcher.setWindowCreator(windowCreator); 

        nsIDOMWindow win = windowWatcher.openWindow(null, "http://google.com", "MAIN_WIN","chrome,resizable,centerscreen", null);
        windowWatcher.setActiveWindow( win ); 

        nsIComponentManager componentManager = mozilla.getComponentManager();
        String NS_IWEBBROWSER_CID = "F1EAC761-87E9-11d3-AF80-00A024FFC08C"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        nsIWebBrowser webBrowser = (nsIWebBrowser) componentManager.createInstance(NS_IWEBBROWSER_CID, null, nsIWebBrowser.NS_IWEBBROWSER_IID);
        webBrowser.setContainerWindow(this);
        webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(this, nsIWebProgressListener.NS_IWEBPROGRESSLISTENER_IID);


//      nsIWebNavigation webNavigation=(nsIWebNavigation)webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
//      webNavigation.loadURI("http://www.zdnet.com", nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, null, null, null);
//      

        nsIBaseWindow baseWindow = (nsIBaseWindow) webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIBaseWindow.NS_IBASEWINDOW_IID);             
        long handle=FindWindow.getHWND( frameTitle );

        baseWindow.initWindow(handle, 0, 0, 0,350,350);
        baseWindow.create();
        baseWindow.setVisibility(true);




//      
//      nsIDOMWindow domWin=webBrowser.getContentDOMWindow();
//      nsIDOMEventTarget domEventTarget= (nsIDOMEventTarget)domWin.queryInterface(nsIDOMEventTarget.NS_IDOMEVENTTARGET_IID);
//      domEventTarget.addEventListener("click", new EventListener(), false);
//      
        //Hide JFrame after it have been initialized
        f.setVisible(true);
//      
//      nsIWebNavigation webNavigation=(nsIWebNavigation)webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
//      webNavigation.loadURI("http://www.zdnet.com", nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, null, null, null);
//      
        appStartup.run(); 
        System.out.println("try termEmbedding"); 
        try { 
            System.out.println("mozilla.termEmbedding(); START"); 
            mozilla.termEmbedding(); 
            System.out.println("mozilla.termEmbedding(); FINISHED"); 
        } 
        catch (XPCOMException e) { 
            System.out.println("Fehler: XPCOMException"); 
        } 
        System.out.println("finished termEmbedding"); 
        System.out.println("All done"); 
    }



    public void onLocationChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, nsIURI location) {
        c("onLocationChange");

    }

    public void onProgressChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, int curSelfProgress, int maxSelfProgress, int curTotalProgress, int maxTotalProgress) {
        c("onProgressChange");

    }

    public void onSecurityChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long state) {
        c("onSecurityChange");

    }

    public void onStateChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long stateFlags, long status) {
        c("onStateChange");

    }

    public void onStatusChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long status, String message) {
        c("onStatusChange");

    }

    public nsISupports queryInterface(String uuid) {
        c("queryInterface");
        return null;
    }



    public nsISupports queryReferent(String uuid) {
        c("queryReferent");
        return null;
    }

    public nsISupports getInterface(String uuid) {
        c("getInterface");
        return null;
    }
    private void c(Object o){
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    public void destroyBrowserWindow() {
        c("destroyBrowserWindow");

    }

    public void exitModalEventLoop(long status) {
        c("exitModalEventLoop");

    }

    public long getChromeFlags() {
        c("getChromeFlags");
        return 0;
    }

    public nsIWebBrowser getWebBrowser() {
        c("getWebBrowser");     
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isWindowModal() {
        c("isWindowModal");     
        return false;
    }

    public void setChromeFlags(long chromeFlags) {
        c("setChromeFlags");    

    }

    public void setStatus(long statusType, String status) {
        c("setStatus"); 

    }

    public void setWebBrowser(nsIWebBrowser webBrowser) {
        c("setWebBrowser");         
    }

    public void showAsModal() {
        c("showAsModal");   

    }

    public void sizeBrowserTo(int acx, int acy) {
        c("sizeBrowserTo"); 

    }

    public boolean onHistoryGoBack(nsIURI backURI) {
        c("onHistoryGoBack");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryGoForward(nsIURI forwardURI) {
        c("onHistoryGoForward");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryGotoIndex(int index, nsIURI gotoURI) {
        c(" onHistoryGotoIndex");
        return false;
    }

    public void onHistoryNewEntry(nsIURI newURI) {
        c(" onHistoryNewEntry");
    }

    public boolean onHistoryPurge(int numEntries) {
        c(" onHistoryPurge");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryReload(nsIURI reloadURI, long reloadFlags) {
        c(" onHistoryReload");
        return false;
    }


} //public class JavaXPCOM_test1[/code]
```

Comment: You're loading a library, NativeWindow.dll.  Where does that come from?

Comment: This is my custom library that I created for finding Native Handle from java via jni based on http://www.comanswer.com/question/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window

Comment: Is there any maven repository for the mozilla dependencies?

Comment: Code is having errors can you give me the complete code with all libraries...Thanks

Comment: What is browser controller in main???? where it is declered? and where to find NativeWindow.dll

Comment: I will have to look for the project, and I will post a link to it after I make sure it compiles

Comment: It no longer works as JavaXPCOM was dropped from XulRunner and XulRunner was dropped from Mozilla Firefox later.

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here (Best Java/Swing browser component?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863) - and from my own testing - [djproject](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) seems to be the best.

It has last been updated March 2009 and some demo links are broken.. so the project seems not to be too active right now.. Still: When I needed it in 2010 it was awesome.

Comment: djproject uses org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser which no longer supports Mozilla Firefox: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html?cp=2_1_0_193 "MOZILLA is deprecated and is no longer supported"

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You could port your UI (or at least part of it) to SWT and then use the Browser component (see [this FAQ item](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#printmozillapath)).

If you can't port your UI to SWT, then you *can* embed your Swing UI in SWT (SWT `Shell` == Swing `JFrame`). But there will be some pain ahead.

**Update:** Firefox is no longer supported by SWT. Currently supported is the system's default browser or WebKit (see https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/search?q=BrowserFactory&unscoped_q=BrowserFactory).

Comment: org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser no longer supports Mozilla Firefox: https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html?cp=2_1_0_193 "MOZILLA is deprecated and is no longer supported"

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search returns a product called [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) that does this.

However, I would question whether you really need a full blown browser component like Firefox in your application. What do you need it for in your application?

Comment: jxbrowser is comercial. You need ~$1500 USD for use these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

How about embedding your GUI inside the browser instead, with an applet, GWT or another rich client approach?