# Swing application with embedded Selenium-controlled Firefox instance

Tags: java, swing, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to run a Selenium controlled Firefox instance and to embed it into a Swing application?

If not with Swing, any other Java GUI library will do too.

Comment: This is possible and has been answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020854/embed-firefox-browser-in-java-swing

Comment: I am not sure if that is the solution because i do not use a plain Firefox browser, but a Selenium controlled WebDriver instance which executes Firefox.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: A recorder application which is able to react on user input in a firefox browser while giving further functionality in a Java GUI. And everyhing should be in one app window.

Comment: Did you  solve this? How?

Comment: I didn't complete this project. If I'd want to start it now, i would investigate if [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Jayan Just stumbled upon this one: https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-recorder - should be very close to what i was asking here