# How to embed Mozilla firefox 17 inside java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, firefox, mozilla

I am trying to run mozilla firefox within java desktop application.
I gone through [Embed Firefox browser in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020854/embed-firefox-browser-in-java-swing)
this link but look like it will not work now as it requires MozillaInterfaces.jar file which is not available in latest releases of xulrunner sdk zip file.

So can somebody help me how can do this?
Please reply with honest answers(i dont want to close/remove this question)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Desktop#browse()` instead.

Comment: @trashgod I am Software developer so i know how to use desktop browser my friend But i need to create some custom stuff for my client thats why i posted this question here

Comment: `Desktop#browse()` can display anything the user's browser can display, custom or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MozSwing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/) allows you to embed Firefox into your Java/Swing application

Comment: also, an alternative to embedding Mozilla's Firefox in your Java Application would be to use Chromium with the help of this [Java Wrapper for the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](http://code.google.com/p/javachromiumembedded/)

Comment: how can i inject a js into that mozswing? for instance, i need to manipulate the appearence of an image....

Comment: MozSwing uses XulRunner which was dropped from Mozilla Firefox.