# JLabel HTML4 support

Tags: java, html, swing

My question is if JLabel (java swing) supports html4 and css2. I know, it supports html3.2 but I want newer version.

Or is there another way to display html4 on a jPanel.

Comment: I can't even find *any* official documentation on the HTML support in Swing ... All there seems to be is the page in the Java Tutorials which doesn't really contain much info apart from a short introduction.

Comment: why not check for yourself ...just test it create your own label with some html4? :)

Comment: Of course I tried it and then I searched about it, but all I found was nothing, Only one guy in a forum had the same question and he didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: no; HTML 3 only, before CSS.

The "HTML" supported by JLabel, JButton, etc, is things like `<font color="" face="" />` and `<a href="#">` to provide inline styling of label textual content.

To indicate that an HTML supporting component contains HTML, the string value must be wrapped in `"<html></html>"`; this is for backward compatibility with existing code. For example:

```
button = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
```

Further information can be seen here: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JLabel.html and documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

JLabel does not provide an implementation of the CSS 2.x visual formatting model, so HTML4 style="" attributes and CSS box formatting will not work. If you want rich HTML formatting support then you'll need to use a web-browser component.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! But do you know any good web-browser component? and can I use it only to display html from a String (I mean not to load a webpage or open an html document)

Comment: There's a variety of browser components that work with Swing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component . You can provide raw HTML within a String object to these components fine (as well as by downloading a page or manipulating the DOM yourself).