# Open source java browser component for swing suggestion

Tags: java, swing, browser, jcomponent

I am looking for an open source browser component like the ones in DJ Project (http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html) for SWING.  I tried using DJ Project (which I learned about from [Best Java/Swing browser component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component)), but I noticed that it hasn't been updated in recent months.

If there is an easy way to make a web browser using JInternalFrame, that would be awesome as well.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can embed a JavaFx WebView in a JPanel.

Comment: *"I noticed that it hasn't been updated in recent months."*  What's to update?

Comment: @AndrewThompson unless a project has a completely empty bug list (and DJProject doesn't), a lack of updates and news typically indicates that a developer has abandoned a project, which is especially bad when a project only has one high profile developer. Using a dead project for something new is usually a bad idea.