# Is it possible to embed an Iframe into a Java program

Tags: java, iframe

I would like to know if it is possible to to embed an youtube Iframe in a Java program. I know that you can put `html` in a `JLabel` but it didn't work. All I did was

```
JLabel video = new JLabel("video url here");
```

So I don't really know what to do. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194022/possible-to-make-a-iframe-in-a-java-applet)but it didn't help. Can you even put an iframe in Java?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to embedd a web browser into the frame using third party libraries, for example you could use [JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html).
[Here](http://revolucionlibrary.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/how-its-made-youtube-player-in-java/)'s a good description how to play youtube using JWebBrowser class.

Answer (score 0):

Swing supports html content, but swing controls are not browser analog.
May be it will be solution for you:
[Best Java/Swing browser component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component)