# Which Java/Swing can reads high quality of HTML and CSS instead of JEditorPane?

Tags: java, html, swing, netbeans

For a long time i'm trying to make a browser with java (note that i'm using NetBeans 8.0) i have the button that open an Url in a JEditorPane but after searching i descover that the JEditorPane can't read a high quality of HTML and CSS. i have looked for JWebPane but that's not ever released. So what's the best Swing that read a high quality of HTML and CSS.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component perhaps be of help?

Comment: Swing JComponents suppors Html <= 3.2, have to use JavaFX

Comment: @mKorbel and how i can use JavaFX would you mind showing me some code to explain ?